# How to add UIImageView on popup block in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup

Hi I am very new to iOS and in my project iI have created one `UITableView` with images as like my below screen ok that's fine

And here when I tapped on tableView images I want show that related row images with popup block using one `UIView`.

But using my code image is not showing on popup `UIView`. Please see my below screen image is not adding on `UIView` popup block please help me some one.

## My Code:

```
#import "imageTableViewController.h"

@interface imageTableViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *mainTable;
    NSMutableArray *imageArray;
    UIButton *imageButton;
    UIView *popUpView;
    BOOL isFullScreen;
    CGRect prevFrame;
}

@end

@implementation imageTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"flower.jpeg",@"Bird.jpg",@"Browser.jpeg", nil];
    mainTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)];
    mainTable.dataSource = self;
    mainTable.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mainTable];

    popUpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 25, 25)];
    popUpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
    [mainTable addSubview:popUpView];

    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flower.jpeg"];
    [popUpView addSubview:imageView];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return imageArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    imageButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    [imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:imageButton];


    return Cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60;
}

-(void)imgToFullScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (!isFullScreen) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            popUpView.hidden = NO;
            prevFrame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 25, 25);
            [popUpView setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 50, 150, 150)];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = TRUE;
        }];
        return;
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [popUpView setFrame:prevFrame];

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = FALSE;
            popUpView.hidden = YES;
        }];
        return;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if `[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower.jpeg"]` returns nil? Try to make the backgroundColor of the imageView green or whatever to see if it is correctly positioned.

Comment: do i have to set imageView background color as green?

Comment: not only UIimageview even labels and buttons also not adding on popup UIview

Comment: Yes for example. This way you can see if the imageview is presented. If you see the green square, this means that you have a problem with the image. If not, you have a problem with adding views to popup.

Comment: no not working i have set imageview backgroud color green

Comment: okey, and for what reason do you do `popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98567/discussion-between-krish-and-fabio-berger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's happened because of

```
popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
```

you create view and scale it to really small, also all subview will be downscaled. And then in show animation block you change frame of popup, but you have to change scale like:

```
popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1, 1);
```

**Edit due comment**

> hmm yes that's fine and one small problem is coming @in.disee that is
>   when i zoom in popup block images are popup like my above screen and
>   when i zoom out that images are must zoom out near related
>   rows,understand?

Your current realisation have few problems including:

- Your architecture do not allow you get index path of selected cell - it will be a problem anyway, so among other you have to make this part.

It will be too hard explain in words everything you have to chage, so i write code for you) I almost do not change your code, but it would be cool if you change it to the way i write mine, because it's more convenient to apple guides

What i do:
1) create custom class for cell
2) add ability for cell say something to tableview via delegation pattern
3) when user click on button in cell - cell tells to tableview, which button of which was was pressed
4) table view convert frame of cell's image to own coordinates and show popup

you can just replace you code with this one:

```
#import "imageTableViewController.h"


@class CustomCell;
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didSelectImageNamed:(NSString *)name fromCell:(CustomCell *)cell;
@end

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *imageBtn;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGRect imageRect;
@end

@implementation CustomCell
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self){
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)imageRect {
    return self.imageBtn.frame;
}

- (void)setup {
    self.imageBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    [self.imageBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageBtn];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [self.imageBtn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)setImageName:(NSString *)imageName {
    _imageName = imageName;
    [self.imageBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)imgToFullScreen:(UIButton *)sender {//btw it's not UITapGestureRecognizer *
    [self.delegate didSelectImageNamed:self.imageName fromCell:self];
}

@end


@interface imageTableViewController ()
<CustomCellDelegate>
@end

@implementation imageTableViewController {
    UITableView *mainTable;
    NSMutableArray *imageArray;
    UIButton *imageButton;
    UIView *popUpView;
    BOOL isFullScreen;

    CGRect prevFrame;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"flower.jpeg",@"Bird.jpg",@"Browser.jpeg", nil];
    mainTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)];
    mainTable.dataSource = self;
    mainTable.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mainTable];

    popUpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 25, 25)];
    popUpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    popUpView.hidden = YES;
    [mainTable addSubview:popUpView];

    UIView * imageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255./255. green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    [popUpView addSubview:imageView];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return imageArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    CustomCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        Cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        Cell.delegate = self;
    }
    Cell.imageName = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return Cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60;
}

-(void)imgToFullScreen:(NSString *)imageName fromRect:(CGRect)frame {

    if (!isFullScreen) {

        [popUpView setFrame:frame];
        [popUpView setHidden:NO];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [popUpView setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 50, 150, 150)];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = YES;
            prevFrame = frame;
        }];
        return;
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [popUpView setFrame:prevFrame];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = NO;
            popUpView.hidden = YES;
        }];
        return;
    }
}


#pragma mark - CustomCellDelegate

- (void)didSelectImageNamed:(NSString *)name fromCell:(CustomCell *)cell {
    CGRect imageFrame = cell.imageRect;
    CGRect imageFrameGlobalCoord = [mainTable convertRect:imageFrame fromView:cell];

    [self imgToFullScreen:name fromRect:imageFrameGlobalCoord];
}

@end
```

Comment: hmm yes that's fine and one small problem is coming @in.disee that is when i zoom in popup block images are popup like my above screen and when i zoom out that images are must  zoom out near related rows,understand?

Comment: if solution is ok for you - please, mark answer as correct